# how to create stub DNS zone for emulating my customer production environment?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory

Is it possible to emulate my customer production environment inside my AD domain by just creating the same domain inside my primary DNS server ?

Can I created mycustomer.com DNS zone (STUB) just for the sake of listing few database servers and application servers and then for the other DNS records eg. MX, NS and the other refer to the REAL MX record entry so that my Exchange Server email flow is unaffected to mycustomer.com ?

because if I just create A record in my current domain for some of the servers, the FQDN is not exactly what I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stub zone is not what you want. You'll want to create a standard forward lookup zone for the domain in question, if I'm understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

I'm currently doing something similar in order to troubleshoot a suspected DNS issue with an external email provider. I simply created a new standard forward lookup zone in my AD integrated DNS for the external domain and populated it with the relevant records for the external domain (A, MX, etc). This essentially makes my AD\DNS server authoratative (internally) for the external domain, eliminating the suspected problems with the external name servers.

Comment: Glad to help...